# Why does intellisense quit working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm working in an ASPX page where intellisense is not functioning. The page compiles and functions correctly - but if I intentionally create a syntax error, instead of placing the message in-line it's being displayed in the top line - the `<%@ Page Title="Stuff" Language="C#"...%>`

In the same project, but a different page, everything works as expected.

Declaration:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OrderRow>" %>`

Comment: Could you post the entire `Page` declaration line (the one that's being underlined in red)?

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OrderRow>" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally found the condition that was preventing Intellisense:

The original page had a code block:

```
<%
=paymentAmt%>
```

At one point during my editing I collapsed that whitespace for sake of readability to:

```
<%=paymentAmt%>
```

Intellisense highlighting reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Curiously have you updated your project from Visual Studio 2005/2008?

Myself and my work colleagues had a similar situation, and I managed to fix it by running `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`. This completely wiped all my user data (as hinted by the argument!) and so I had re-add my themes, settings and keyboard shortcuts.

It's had varying degrees of success, I'll be honest, but it seems to be quite a serious issue for a lot of developers right now.

Comment: The project did begin life under 08 but has been living under 10 for quite a while.